# how to generate bundle for mac on symfony

Tags: macos, symfony, bundle

how to generate bundle for mac on symfony2 ? I didn't generate bundle on mac terminal

**erdem-ldz:~ erdemildiz$ php /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfony  generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml**

didn't work?

Comment: What kind of error it generates?

Comment: it didn't give any message , but didn't generate bundle

Comment: erdem-ldz:~ erdemildiz$ php /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfony  generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml

Answer (score 1):

I fix my problem.
1- on terminal cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfony 
2- change  permission symfony/app/logs/dev.log to write and read
3- rewrite app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml